# can ob_start() influence included and required files?

Tags: php, cron

I have some php file "A" which is called by cron, from console ("php -q" command). That php file requires php file "B". File "B" is used at many places in project, and starts with `if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();`It works fine from browser, but when used by cron, file "A" requires file "B", file "B" tries to start the session and i got "session headers sent" notice. I have tried to inculude `ob_start()` in file "A", right before `require_once("B")` (and of course, `ob_clean()`) later, but error persists!

What am i doing wrong? How can i (from file "A") prevent file "B" from trying to send anything to console?

Comment: You can't use sessions on the command line, it doesn't make any sense as there is no browser to send cookies to and only one request.

Comment: Why do you think that anything was send? And what's wrong in sending anything *to console*?

Comment: @Dan - i know, that's thhe point of this post :) @Col. because when file "B" tries to open a session, error is writen in "error_log"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable [session.use_cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies) in your CLI php script via `ini_set()` or via php.ini configuration. This way `session_start()` don't try to send cookies. You have to check the cache settings for sessions as well as `session_start()` send HTTP headers regarding caches, too.

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0); // disable using cookies for session ID (cookies = headers)
session_cache_limiter(false);      // disable sending cache headers
// ...
session_start();
```

Comment: Hmmm thanks for advice, but can i disable "use_cookies" from php? Only when file "A" is called? I can't access php.ini at my site's server :\

Comment: @guest86: Yes, as I said: "... via ini_set() or via ...".

Comment: Nice! so, should i "ini_set" use_cookies off before "require_once" and then set it back on? Or server will revert it to default later?

Comment: @guest86: For the current request/script (and only for this execution) its disabled. This does not affect the php.ini configuration or the web server behavior. You don't need to set it back to "on".

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I'll accept this answer even if maybe it's not the quickest :)

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION are mostly based on cookie so can't work in CLI

Comment: I know! I just wan't to use standard php file (B), created for browser usage, but to somehow prevent it (via file A) from trying to open a session! That's why i placed "ob_start" before "require_once(B)" and called "ob_clean" after "require_once"

Comment: if i understood you can do this: declare a generic variable in teh file A like: $sessionCheck=1; 

Now in the file B do if(!isset($_SESSION,$sessionCheck))

Answer (score 0):

ob_start() has to be called before any output. so, at the top of file "A," maybe.

Also, I think $_SESSION is a superglobal and is always set, so the if(!isset($_SESSION)) might do nothing (never true).

Comment: `$_SESSION` only exists if a session is loaded/started, not always.

Answer (score 0):

You can do $_SESSION = true; in file "A" which would make the var set and it won't start the session. It is dirty but it does work.

Comment: This sound easy! Does anyone see something wrong with this approach?